# How to make when cell selected custom image is change?

Tags: ios, swift

SHOW MY QUESTION VIDEO : [question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcWwB.jpg)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell") as! TableViewCell
    cell.lblName.text! = nameArr[indexPath.row]
    cell.iconImg.image = UIImage(systemName: "chevron.down")
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if self.SelectedIndex == indexPath.row && isCollapse == true {
        return 283
    } else {
        return 40
    }
}
var select = false

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    if SelectedIndex == indexPath.row {
        if self.isCollapse == false {
            self.isCollapse = true
        } else {
            self.isCollapse = false
        }
    } else {
        self.isCollapse = true
    }
    self.SelectedIndex = indexPath.row
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    cell.iconImg.image = UIImage(systemName: "chevron.up"
}
```

I typed the extendable cell code like above.
I want to `chevron.down`(V) this image to `cell.iconImg` to (^)  .

I tried `cell.isSelected` But didn't work. How can I solve this problem?

[problem1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41Djn.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Just call reload tableview in did select and change image in cellForRowAt method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell") as! TableViewCell
    cell.lblName.text! = nameArr[indexPath.row]
   cell.iconImg.image = UIImage(systemName: self.isCollapse ?  "chevron.down" : "chevron.down")
   return cell
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if self.isCollapse == false {
            self.isCollapse = true
        } else {
            self.isCollapse = false
        }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: hmmm. i try it but whole cell image is change at once. but thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need update the code of cellForRowAt like as following.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell") as! TableViewCell
    cell.lblName.text! = nameArr[indexPath.row]
    Bool isExpand = (self.SelectedIndex == indexPath.row && self.isCollapse == true);
    cell.iconImg.image = UIImage(systemName: isExpand ?  "chevron.up" : "chevron.down")
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if self.SelectedIndex == indexPath.row && isCollapse == true {
        return 283
    } else {
        return 40
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    if SelectedIndex == indexPath.row {
        if self.isCollapse == false {
            self.isCollapse = true
        } else {
            self.isCollapse = false
        }
    } else {
        self.isCollapse = true
    }

    tableView.reloadData();
}
```

Comment: Thx for helping. I tried that code but when collapse happened have a problem i add a image link.

Comment: I Solved problem with 'tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)' to 'reloadData()'